# Send the content-type to webapi from kenod dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to send the contentType as "application/json" to webApi controller. below is the code which i used and it is not working.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                  .Name("ddlPatientClass").AutoBind(true)
                                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 67px!important;" })
                                  .DataTextField("ModuleName")
                                  .DataValueField("RoleId")   
                                  .ContentType("application/json")        
                                  .DataSource(source =>
                                  {
                                      source.Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "MedicalVisit", Action = "GetPatientClass" })).Type(HttpVerbs.Get));//.Type(HttpVerbs.Get).Data("ModuleParamCP"));
                                  })
                                )
```

Comment: How does your controller looks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@Html`helper class, you can use below Kendo UI JQyery dropdown to bind JSON data as below.

**HTML**

```
<input id="ddlPatientClass" name="ddlPatientClass" class="custom-select" style="width: 100%;" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = [
        { text: "0", value: "0" },
        { text: "10", value: "10" },
        { text: "25", value: "25" },
        { text: "30", value: "30" },
        { text: "100", value: "100" }
    ];
    // This data you can get from WebApi - using Ajax call

    // After get JSON data from webApi - you can create DropDownList as below


    $("#ddlPatientClass").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: data,
        index: 0,
        optionLabel: "-- Choose % --",
    });
});
```

Comment: My question is  how can i send the contenttype value to Api ControllerMethod using kendo dropdown list. Just like in ajax we use contentType: "application/json" in same way i need to pass contentType to api